# sqplus in shell script with spool not working

Tags: oracle, shell, ksh

I have a shell script where I do a simple query and I'm trying to spooling. But not works, the spool file is not generated. If I do inside oracle session I don't have any problem. I thing is a problem in my code but I can't see anything.

connection_script.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh

query="$1"

sqlplus -s /nolog <<EOF | egrep -v Conectado
  connect ${USER_QUERY}/${PASS_QUERY}@${CONNECTION}
  ${query}
EOF
```

and script with spool:

```
$PATH/connection_script.sh "
set termout off
set verify off
set linesize 90
set pagesize 20
set serverout on

spool myreport3.csv
select name, description from tableA;

exit
"
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: `$PATH`? Is that supposed to be `$PWD`? What do you see on screen when you run this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in quotes ". I must space quotes and everithing is ok. Thanks